# Need help to create Confusion Matrix and Prediction Code

Tags: image, prediction, confusion-matrix, image-classification

```
model_SVC = SVC(C=1000,gamma=0.1, kernel='rbf')
model_SVC.fit(X_train,Y_train) #CASIA2

predictions=model_SVC.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(Y_test,predictions))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_test,predictions))
print(classification_report(Y_test,predictions))
```

**I need help in creating a confusion matrix using seaborn and a code to predict the image.
Can someone help me with this?**

Comment: What do you mean by `code to predict the image.`? Doesn't the code above do the predictions? Are you looking to use the output of `confusion_matrix()` displayed as a plot or something else?

Comment: Yes..This gives the result. I would like to see the confusion_matrix() as a plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code along with some random code to generate data and [ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html) to generate the confusion matrix. You can change the parameters as required to suit your needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

model_SVC = SVC(C=1000,gamma=0.1, kernel='rbf')
model_SVC.fit(X_train,Y_train) #CASIA2

predictions=model_SVC.predict(X_test)

#print(accuracy_score(Y_test,predictions))
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test,predictions)
#print(classification_report(Y_test,predictions))

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=model_SVC.classes_)
font={'size':'14'}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=[6,6]
disp.plot(cmap='Blues',values_format='0.2f')
#plt.colorbar(im,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]